# Why is Second Deferred not getting triggered?

Tags: jquery

I am just trying some demo code with JQuery deferred and I am not able to understand the behaviour.

This is my code:

```
( function(){
        var createDef = function(data){
            var def = new $.Deferred();
        setTimeout(()=>{
            alert(data);
                def.resolve(data);
        },0);
        return def;
    };

    $
      .when(createDef('hello'),createDef('world'))
      .done((msg)=>{
          alert('done ' + msg);
      })
      .fail((msg)=>{
          alert('fail ' + msg);
      })
      .always((msg)=>{
          alert('always ' + msg);
      });
})();
```

in the line `def.resolve(data);` in both cases def is in pending state but still only first message i.e. hello is triggered, why is second message not coming to done callback?

Comment: Your code is working fine for me https://jsfiddle.net/vym79Lz0/ , share the jquery version you are using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add one more parameter to done() as shown below:

```
( function(){
    var createDef = function(data){
        var def = new $.Deferred();
    setTimeout(()=>{
        alert(data);
            def.resolve(data);
    },0);
    return def;
};

$
  .when(createDef('hello'),createDef('world'))
  .done((msg, worldcallbackresult)=>{ 
      //add another parameter to indicate createDef('world')
      alert('done ' + msg + 'world callback' + worldcallbackresult);
  })
  .fail((msg)=>{
      alert('fail ' + msg);
  })
  .always((msg)=>{
      alert('always ' + msg);
  });
})();
```